# Getting type of Object's value from key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I created a data.

```js
type PenType = {
    color: string
}

type PencilType = {
    darkness: string
}

const data: {
    pen: PenType,
    pencil: PencilType
} = {
    pen: {
        color: "blue",
    },
    pencil: {
        darkness: "2B"
    }
};

type DataKeys = keyof typeof data;
```

I now have Object data with keys and values. I did create a function to get value from the  data.

```js
type MyReturnType = PenType | PencilType;

const getMyData = (keyToGet: DataKeys): MyReturnType => {
    return data[keyToGet];
}

const finalData = getMyData('pen');

console.log(finalData);
```

This works completely fine. But the issue is, I want to get correct type in my `finalData`. Since I have tried to access pen, I want return type to be `PenType`, not `PenType | PencilType`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-hnle7p?file=/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) to be `PenType | PencilType`, then that's what the function will return no matter what.

If, instead, you want the compiler to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the value passed in as `keyToGet`, you need `getMyData()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type, with a generic type parameter as follows:

```
const getMyData = <K extends DataKeys>(keyToGet: K) => {
    return data[keyToGet];
}
```

Here, `getMyData` is generic in `K`, a type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to `DataKeys`, and the type of the `keytoGet` function parameter.

I didn't annotate the return type explicitly. Instead, performing the indexing operation `data[keyToGet]` and returning it means the returned type is inferred by the compiler to be a generic [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
/* {
    pen: PenType;
    pencil: PencilType;
}[K] */
```

So when you call `getMyData('pen')`, `K` is inferred as `"pen"`, and then the return type will be `{pen: PenType; pencil: PencilType}["pen"]`, an indexed access type that evaluates to `PenType`:

```
const finalData = getMyData('pen');
// const finalData: PenType

console.log(finalData.color.toUpperCase()); // "BLUE"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChB2AVc0C8UDeAoKUDGA9gDYEBOAXFAM7CkCW8A5lgL5ZaiSwJ51HJd02XABMAhqQDW8CFSqUa9Jq3aF4NKOOBjKwqJHiU4SFABoc+nnyNX+KVlCEWDui7kIkKUAEQAjIgCuEN7muCyhlvC8RK64ohLSsvI+AEwAQt4WbCwA3Oyc0AAiYtoA0hAgVI5QkhUEAGZQBQ2aJWJ5WGoajBDAALIgxdrVADylUBAAHsAIIlVDYuWVAHwAFLUgiAQA4r2UpQCUjsuYblCkvQGk8K3aANobW7vAALp5bAD0AFSncZE2JkgeT+BmiAOiAgg7zupReUC+H1UBHUwCg9QYYiIC2qPX6gzaqwA5AZCQc8h8PvhkRp0fBMQsAZCkepiBAAHQkRirWn0tpsjxkNnAAgAVTAkFIAGExFQIKsDmSoBSfGkADIigCi3iAA)